# Get min-max values of a raster and populate two parameters with the values in tool validation script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster, arcgis-10.2, tool-validation

I am customizing the script tool behaviour of a custom script and would like to get the min-max values from a raster `self.params[0]` and populate the next two parameters, `self.params[1]` and `self.params[2]`, with these values. Here is what I have so far but of course, it doesn't work.

```
  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parmater
    has been changed."""

    if self.params[0].altered and self.params[0].value:
        paramInRaster = arcpy.Raster(self.params[0])
        minVal = paramInRaster.minimum
        maxVal = paramInRaster.maximum
        self.params[1].value = minVal
        self.params[2].value = maxVal
    return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following line, you are grabbing the parameter object instead of the value:

```
     paramInRaster = arcpy.Raster(self.params[0])
```

Try changing it to:

```
     paramInRaster = arcpy.Raster(self.params[0].value)
```